# Validating React forms with Cornice/Colander/Pyramid

Tags: reactjs, pyramid, colander, cornice

We are using Cornice for server-side REST API. Frontend is using React. We'd like to have frontend forms to post to Cornice and give proper validation results.

- Are there any standard practices of form submission / error result format
- Are there any standard practices for rendering forms in React so that Cornice validation results would be correctly dropped over the fields (like what Deform et. al. do on the server side.)

Any pointers welcome.

Comment: I never used React with Cornice, but I've used Backbone and Angular. In both cases, I used Colander schemas to do the validation, and created a JS function to parse the error result into something usable by the JS framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a project called Kinto that is doing all of that.

- They have a standard for JSON errors: http://kinto.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/1.x/cliquet/errors.html?highlight=errors
- They have a way of validating data against a JSON schema: http://kinto.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/1.x/collections.html?highlight=schema#collection-json-schema

Do not hesitate to join [#kinto on freenode](https://kiwiirc.com/client/irc.freenode.net/?#kinto)

Comment: About React.JS forms you can have a look at: https://github.com/Kinto/kinto-admin and https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form/